# Mongodb start up error

Tags: mongodb, database

I am new to the `mongo` db.I just installed it over my ubuntu 11.04 system and when I typed `mongo` in terminal it showed like this

```
MongoDB shell version: 1.6.3
Thu Mar 22 15:07:33 *** warning: spider monkey build without utf8 support.  consider rebuilding with utf8 support
connecting to: test
>
```

Can some one tell me  where I am wrong and how to solve this problem.Ant help and suggestions will be highly appreciable.

Comment: See http://yoodey.com/how-install-latest-mongodb-version-ubuntu and/or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268132/mongodb-doesnt-understand-utf-8

Comment: Have you installed the right package?

Did you try this solution? http://realguess.net/node/166

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ubuntu repositories have a very old version of mongoDB - the current stable branch is 2.0 at the time of writing and yours is 1.6, you could try fixing the error but it's not really worth it.  You should get an up to date version from the official 10gen repos as described here and uninstall the one you have now:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ubuntu+and+Debian+packages

General procedure would be:

- Remove Ubuntu version (apt-get remove mongodb)
- Add new repo line and gpg key as described above
- Install 10gen version (apt-get update; apt-get install mongodb-10gen)